# How to pass params to function from inside multiple ng-repeat directives?

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with passing parameters through `ng-repeat`. I have three nested `ng-repeat` and inside I want to pass some data to my function.

This is in my HTML :

```
<div ng-repeat="x in players" ng-controller="filterClubCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="z in playerLastDays" ng-if="x.player_id == z.player_id">
        <div ng-repeat="y in teams" ng-if="y.id == z.team_id">
            <div class="percentageWeeks" ng-if="filterSmalerThan(z.avgDays,x.avgWeek)">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="partials/club/img/arrow_down.png" />
                <p>{{weeklyGrowth(z.avgDays, x.avgWeek, y.avgWeekTeam) | number:2 }}% in last {{days}} days</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is in function my controller :

```
$scope.weeklyGrowth = function(avgDays, avgWeek, avgWeekTeam) {
    $scope.avgWeeklyGrowth = 0;
    $scope.avgWeeklyGrowt = avgDays / avgWeekTeam * 100 - avgWeek / avgWeekTeam * 100;
    return $scope.avgWeeklyGrowth;
};
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are having ? Are you getting an error is nothing being displayed ? Also, can you display the contents of `players`, `playerLastDays` and `teams`. Or better yet paste the entirety of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's caused by a typo error inside your method; since you're mistyping the value `$scope.avgWeeklyGrowth` leading to declare a new value `$scope.avgWeeklyGrowt` instead and keep the value of `$scope.avgWeeklyGrowth` as zero:

```
$scope.weeklyGrowth = function (avgDays, avgWeek, avgWeekTeam) {

$scope.avgWeeklyGrowth = 0; 

// Old line that makes the issue: $scope.avgWeeklyGrowt = avgDays / avgWeekTeam * 100 - avgWeek / avgWeekTeam * 100;

$scope.avgWeeklyGrowth = avgDays / avgWeekTeam * 100 - avgWeek / avgWeekTeam * 100;

return $scope.avgWeeklyGrowth;}
```

Comment: No, that's my copy paste  error. It doesn't  submit the third parameter in the function

Answer (score 0):

It's was mistake in JSON. I put y.avgWeekTeam but in JSON was avgWeekteam.

Thanks guys for help!